# How to remove a certain value from a table that will vary in size in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm new to the community and I apologize if there is a thread elsewhere, but I could not find it!

I'm currently diving into VBA coding for the first time. I have a file that I dump into a worksheet that currently I'm manually organizing and pushing out. When put into the worksheet, it delimits itself across the cells. This dump file will have varying row and column lengths every time I get it in a given day and dump into a work sheet. For example, one day it may be twenty rows and one day it may be thirty.

A certain roadblock in my VBA code creation process has presented itself. I'm trying to create a code that will parse through the worksheet to remove any time a certain value appears (See below image - I'm referring to the (EXT)). After doing so I'm trying to concatenate the cells in the row up until there is a space (which with the rows that have (EXT), there usually isn't a space after until the (EXT) is removed).

The code I made works for now but I recognize it's not very efficient and not reliable if the names extend longer than two cells. I was hoping someone on here could provide me with guidance. So, I'm looking for two things:

- For the code to scan the whole active used range of the table and remove (EXT). As it may appear in various columns.
- A way to concatenate the cells in every row in the active range from A to the cell before a blank cell

Keep in mind I have no coding background, I'm learning and I'm not familiar with VBA terms and whatnot all that much just yet - so if you could please explain in laymen's terms I'd appreciate it. I hope all of this makes sense... Thanks in advance!

This is just an example of part of what the dump code looks like, so my code probably doesn't match with the example below - I just wanted to provide a visual:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z11Vq.jpg

The code I currently have:

```
Sub DN_ERROR_ORGANIZER()

' Removes any (EXT) in Column 3 in actual dump data file
For i = 200 To 1 Step -1
   If (Cells(i, 3).value = "(EXT)") Then
   Cells(i, 3).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
   End If
Next i

' Removes any (EXT) in Column 4 in actual dump data file
For j = 200 To 1 Step -1
   If (Cells(j, 4).value = "(EXT)") Then
   Cells(j, 4).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
   End If
Next j

' Removes any (EXT) in Column 5 in actual dump data file
For k = 200 To 1 Step -1
   If (Cells(k, 5).value = "(EXT)") Then
   Cells(k, 5).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
   End If
Next k

' Places a new column before A and performs a concatenate on cells B1 and C1 to
' form a name, then copies all through column A1 to repeat on each row
   Columns("A:A").Select
   Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
   Range("A1").Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=PROPER(CONCATENATE(RC[1],"", "", RC[2]))"
   Range("A1").Select
   Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A51")
   Range("A1:A51").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited**: to keep the comma after the first "name" only

this should do:

```
Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range

    With Worksheets("names")
        With Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).EntireRow)
            For Each cell In .Rows
                cell.Cells(1, 2).Value = Replace(Replace(Replace(Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(cell.Value)), " "), "  ", " "), " (EXT)", ""), " ", ", ", , 1)
            Next cell
            .Columns(1).FormulaR1C1 = "=PROPER(RC[1])"
            .Columns(1).Value = .Columns(1).Value
            .Offset(, 1).Resize(, .Columns.Count - 1).ClearContents
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

just remember to change "names" to you actual worksheet name

**edited 2:**
code for stopping cells to be processed at every line at the last one before the first blank one

```
Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range, dataRng As Range

    With Worksheets("names") '<--| change "names" to you actual worksheet name
        Set dataRng = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).EntireRow)
        For Each cell In dataRng.Columns(1).Cells
            cell.Offset(, 1).Value = Replace(Replace(Replace(Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Range(cell, cell.End(xlToRight)).Value)), " "), "  ", " "), " (EXT)", ""), " ", ", ", , 1)
        Next cell
        With dataRng
            .Columns(1).FormulaR1C1 = "=PROPER(RC[1])"
            .Columns(1).Value = .Columns(1).Value
            .Offset(, 1).Resize(, .Columns.Count - 1).ClearContents
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Good work +1.  I based my new answer off of yours.  I think the OP only wants a comma after the last name (first column value).

Comment: @ThomasInzina, you're right, edited accordingly. thanks

Comment: @ThomasInzina 

Thank you both so much for providing the code. Unfortunately Thomas, yours didn't work and produced a #NAME? at the end of each row. With yours user3598756, it works but concatenates the whole row of data. Is there a way to have it only concatenate up until it arrives at the first occurrence of a blank cell? In my original dump data it will have additional data I'm working to format after it. I hope that makes sense? ahaha

Comment: @lejaregg No worries.  I forgot that TestJoin was a new function and not widely available.  Happy Coding!!

Comment: @user3598756: I've tried to strip down your code but it is quite complex for me starting out. I've tried this but can't wrap my head around how I would go about concatenating. I want it to take the first cell in the row, concatenate with ", ", then continue to concatenate the cells in the row until it runs into a blank cell in that row, and then transition to the next row and do the same til it reaches the last row. Thomas: if you have input, it's most definitely welcome!

Comment: @ThomasInzina 

This is the code I have so far:
    `Dim row As Integer
    NumRows = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xldown)).Rows.Count
    Range("A1").Select
    For row = 1 To NumRows
 Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
 ***Code to concatenate***
 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
 Loop
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next`

Comment: @user3598756 This new edit does the same thing as previous and concatenates everything within the row into one cell. I'm just trying to concatenate from first cell in row up until the first blank cell in the same row - leaving the remainder of cells in the row the way they are and continuing into the next row to perform the same action.

Comment: I tested and it gives exactly the result you qualified as "desired" in your linked image.

Comment: @lejaregg, you may very well post a new question once you understand your actual isn't properly put against your actual needs. But you should close this question consistently: if my post answered your question _as you wrote it_, then please accept it. In the meanwhile I'll take a look at your new post.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are quite close to achieve what you are asking for and, based on your request, I will not give you a solution but some guidance to complete it by yourself.

1. First 3 loops: You could simplify by having a single set of nested loops: An outer loop running from 3 to 5, an inner loop running from 200 to 1; the outer loop will run over  index, say "p", the inner over index, say "q", and your reference to cells would become `Cells(q,p)`. If you need to run this over more than 3 rows, just start the outer loop from, say, 3 and till, say 10000 (being 10000 the maximal number of rows your data may display) and add a condition that if the first cell of the row is empty, you exit the outer loop.
2. The second part (this is what I understood) is to take the 2-3 first cells and concatenate them into a new cell (i.e. the column you add at the left). Once again, you can just loop over all your rows (much the same as in the outer loop mentioned above), except that now you will be looking at the cells in columns 2-4 (because you added a column at the left). The same exit condition as above can be used.

I'm not sure if this is what you were looking for, but this is what I *understood* you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

After reading user3598756's answer, I realized that I missed the boat with my original answer.

```
Sub DN_ERROR_ORGANIZER()
    Dim Target As Range
    Set Target = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
    Target.Replace "(EXT)", ""
    With Target.Offset(0, Target.Columns.Count).Resize(, 1)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=PROPER(C1&"", ""&TEXTJOIN("" "",TRUE,RC[-" & (Target.Columns.Count - 1) & "]:RC[-1]))"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

    Target.Delete
End Sub
```

### UPDATE

If you are running an older version of Excel that doesn't support `TEXTJOIN` then use this:

---

```
Sub DN_ERROR_ORGANIZER()
    Dim Data
    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim Text As String
    Set Target = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
    Target.Replace "(EXT)", ""
    Data = Target.Value

    For x = 1 To Target.Rows.Count
        Data(x, 1) = Data(x, 1)
        For y = 2 To Target.Columns.Count
            If Data(x, y) <> vbNullString Then Text = Text & " " & Data(x, y)
        Next
        If Len(Text) Then Data(x, 1) = Data(x, 1) & "," & Text
        Text = vbNullString
    Next
    Target.ClearContents
    Target.Columns(1).Value = Data
End Sub
```